# Weird issue while parsing JSONObjects and converting to Java objects

Tags: java, android, json

This is the first time I am facing a very weird problem. I have a JSONObject mentioned below.:

**Link for the JSON body** (Cant paste JSON body here because of character limit):
http://kolam.vicz.in:7890/games_gifs/

I am parsing the above set of JSONObjects and converting them to Java objects. Below is my code of parsing this JSON body.

```
private void getGameList() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, gameUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray gamesArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("TracingGames");
                    Log.e(TAG, "gameArray length:" + gamesArray.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < gamesArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = gamesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        for (String str : getKeys(obj)) {
                            Log.e(TAG, str);
                            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("kolam")) {

                                /*Section for Learn and Kolam Tracing games start*/
                                //TODO: Need to add the game names to the object (Need server side implementation as well)
                                KolamTracingGames kolamTracingGames = new KolamTracingGames();
                                kolamTracingGames.setKolamGifPath(obj.getString("path"));
                                kolamTracingGames.setKolamLevel(Integer.parseInt(str));
                                kolamTracingGames.setKolamGameName("Kolam Tracing");
                                kolamTracingGames.setX(getXCoordinates(obj));
                                kolamTracingGames.setY(getYCoordinates(obj));
                                kolamObjects.add(kolamTracingGames);
                                break;
                            } else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("level")) {
                                LearnTracingGames learnTracingGames = new LearnTracingGames();
                                learnTracingGames.setLearnGameGifPath(obj.getString("path"));
                                learnTracingGames.setLearnGameLevel(Integer.parseInt(str));
                                learnTracingGames.setGameName("Learn Game");
                                learnTracingGames.setX(getXCoordinates(obj));
                                learnTracingGames.setY(getYCoordinates(obj));
                                learnGameObjects.add(learnTracingGames);
                                Log.e(TAG, learnGameObjects.size() + "");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (gameType.equalsIgnoreCase("Trace the Kolam")) {
                        kolamTraceAdapter = new KolamTraceAdapter(getActivity());
                        kolamTraceAdapter.getGameList(kolamObjects);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(kolamTraceAdapter);
                    } else if (gameType.equalsIgnoreCase("Learn")) {
                        learnGameAdapter = new LearningGameAdapter(getActivity());
                        learnGameAdapter.getGameList(learnGameObjects);
                        Log.e(TAG, "learngameobject size:" + learnGameObjects.size());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(learnGameAdapter);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Learn games");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    Alerter.create(getActivity())
                            .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                            .setText(R.string.network_error)
                            .setDuration(2000)
                            .setBackgroundColorRes(R.color.dot_dark_screen1)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
        request.setTag(TAG);
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

My problem is there are 8 **level** type objects and 4 **kolam** objects (Please refer the JSON body for clarity). I am having two separate POJO classes for them. I am able to parse the JSON body properly but when I am trying to **create Java objects** of those JSONObjects the inner most `for loop` is not running completely. Its stopping after 1 loop.

the inner for loop is not getting executed completely (executing only once but should get executed more then 12 times) if I am doing this (Creating Java Objects):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gamesArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = gamesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        for (String str : getKeys(obj)) {
                            Log.e(TAG, str);
                            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("kolam")) {

                                /*Section for Learn and Kolam Tracing games start*/
                                //TODO: Need to add the game names to the object (Need server side implementation as well)
                                KolamTracingGames kolamTracingGames = new KolamTracingGames();
                                kolamTracingGames.setKolamGifPath(obj.getString("path"));
                                kolamTracingGames.setKolamLevel(Integer.parseInt(str));
                                kolamTracingGames.setKolamGameName("Kolam Tracing");
                                kolamTracingGames.setX(getXCoordinates(obj));
                                kolamTracingGames.setY(getYCoordinates(obj));
                                kolamObjects.add(kolamTracingGames);
                                break;
                            } else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("level")) {
                                LearnTracingGames learnTracingGames = new LearnTracingGames();
                                learnTracingGames.setLearnGameGifPath(obj.getString("path"));
                                learnTracingGames.setLearnGameLevel(Integer.parseInt(str));
                                learnTracingGames.setGameName("Learn Game");
                                learnTracingGames.setX(getXCoordinates(obj));
                                learnTracingGames.setY(getYCoordinates(obj));
                                learnGameObjects.add(learnTracingGames);
                                Log.e(TAG, learnGameObjects.size() + "");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

the `getKeys(JSONObject)` method is below:

```
private static String[] getKeys(JSONObject firstJSONObject) {
        Iterator keysToCopyIterator = firstJSONObject.keys();
        List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (keysToCopyIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keysToCopyIterator.next();
            keysList.add(key);
        }
        return keysList.toArray(new String[keysList.size()]);
    }
```

But If I avoid creating objects inside the `for loop` then the inner `for loop` runs completely.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...why are you trying to parse the JSON yourself? Seeing that you are on Android, have you considered using eg. `Gson`?
Cause then it could in theory be as easy as writing `KolamTracingGmaes games = new Gson().fromJson(response, KolamTracingGames.class)`

Comment: I thought you have `break` statement

Comment: I have tried every possible way.. I can parse the JSON body easily and completely if I am not creating those Java objects. Just commenting those objects setter method lines make the code run successfully. But if I run the above code. Then it's running only for 1 time

Comment: break statement is not the problem here. @Yohannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But If I avoid creating objects inside the for loop then the inner for
>   loop runs completely.

`Integer.parseInt("level")` or `Integer.parseInt("kolam")` which is clearly a crash

Explanation

when your any of `if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("kolam"))` or `else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("level")) {` matches then

you clearly have a crash here , `Integer.parseInt(str)` because `str` will either be `level` or `kolam` which are clearly not `integers`

**Solution** : Don't use `str` instead fetch the values

```
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("kolam")) {
    //... code
    kolamTracingGames.setKolamLevel(obj.optInt(str));
    //... code                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    break;
} else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("level")) {
    //... code
    learnTracingGames.setLearnGameLevel(obj.optInt(str));
    //... code                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    break;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I just came out of my home..will update once that runs successfully..amazing man. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Hiren i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: I just wanted to know. Why didn't the java compiler throw any error or exception regarding that ?

Comment: @Hiren because you applied the `try-catch` and you used `Exception` which will handle every exception but still the exception details is available to you in logcat via `e.printStackTrace();` although to bring a crash just add catch blocks for necessary parsing exceptions like  `JSONException`

Comment: it's always good practice to catch the expected exceptions for quick debugging instead of Exception, use replace `catch (Exception e) {` with `catch (JSONException e) {` to view NumberFormatException